# __NSCFNumber unrecognized selector sent to instance - Weird behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, block, weak-references

I'm having a really strange problem with an object of my class, inside a block a have a weak reference of my View Controller, part of the code in the block is

```
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(reloadItems) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];             
        [weakSelf.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        if (weakSelf.shouldPresentNotification) {
            [[LLAPI sharedInstance] presentLatestNotification];
            weakSelf.shouldPresentNotification = NO;
        }
```

The problem is that probably a couple of my users have experienced this crash 
[__NSCFNumber shouldPresentNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbb3c1937855f68da

Now, I understand that the crash report is telling me that weakSelf is an NSNumber object, but that doesn't really make any sense, and if that is true why would the crash be raised only until the variable "shouldPresentNotification" is accessed?

**EDIT:**
Here is the full stack trace:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182154f5c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000196d4bf80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018215bc6c 

__methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182158c14 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018205cdcc _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  Laclud                         0x00000001001109c4 __38-[LLMainVC processLacludSession]_block_invoke424 (LLMainVC.m:467)
6  Laclud                         0x000000010011055c -[LLMainVC processLacludSession] (LLMainVC.m:516)
7  Laclud                         0x000000010013ff30 __32-[LLGFVC sendFeedback]_block_invoke (LLGiveFeedbackVC.m:137)
8  Laclud                         0x000000010014a40c __41-[LLAPI rateLonJet:like:success:failure:]_block_invoke (LLAPI.m:189)
9  Laclud                         0x000000010034349c __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke236 (RKObjectRequestOperation.m:481)
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001975457b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000197545770 _dispatch_client_callout
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019754ae20 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
13 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018210c258 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
14 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018210a0c0 __CFRunLoopRun
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182038dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018d18c088 GSEventRunModal
17 UIKit                          0x0000000187712f44 UIApplicationMain
18 Laclud                         0x0000000100178900 main (main.m:15)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001975768b8 start
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: show us, what is `weakSelf`

Comment: I edited my question @katleta3000

Comment: Try converting weakSelf to a strong reference (if it's non-nil) before you use it in the block?

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace ?

Comment: I added the Stack trace @deadbeef

Comment: Weird. Have you tried @i_am_jorf solution ? If it doesn't work, try activating NSZombies and show us the result (google for it if you don't know how to do it)